# alert dialog in android should not dismiss

Tags: android, dialog

I am making an application and it has an Alert Dialog in it.

Now i am checking some data I got from AlertDialog editTexts in dialog Positive button OnClick method but the dialog always dismiss if data i got from edittext fields is correct or not.

How can we  disable this feature.

**UPDATED:**

I am gettin Pin Code and Confirm Pin Code from the Dialog Box and in onPositive click i have checked to verify the pin codes.

Now if the pin codes matches then it is calling dialog.dismiss() and if not matching then display a Toast.

But in case of pin code not matched it displays me the message and dismiss the dialog.

I dont want that to be happen.

**MORE UPDATES:**

is there any way that i will disable the OK Button and when data is verified it will enable the positive Button??

Please help

Comment: Can you add some code with you description - it's hard to tell what you want from your question. I'm assuming you want to validate the input data, is that correct? Are you using a subclass of AlertDialog to do this?

Comment: Please add the code where you set up your Alert Dialog. It will be much easier to see where things go wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cap. Thanks for your help. through your guides i have got to know that i can disable the Alert Dialog Button. YES! its possible to disable the buttons.

Answer is:

we can disable the button using:

```
  Button pos =  Dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
  pos.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: how we got dialog.getButton function

Comment: use `getDialog()` method and cast it to `AlertDialog`. Note that this must be performed in onResume, for example, and then you can keep a reference to that object. Example:         `this.okButton = ( (AlertDialog)getDialog() ).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);`

Answer (score 27):

This is the trick (override onClickListener inside onShowListener):

```
final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.my_title)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new Dialog.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {
                                //Do nothing here. We override the onclick
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                .create();

        d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

                Button b = d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // TODO Do something

                        //Dismiss once everything is OK.
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just what i wanted! The only thing is that your app should be running at least in Froyo... for me this is not a problem =)

Comment: What a great solution! Just a small correction: instead of the line `.create()` I had to store the result use `final AlertDialog ad = d.create();`. Then, I had to define `ad`'s (not `d`'s) `setOnShowListener()` method, and similarly use `ad`'s (not `d`'s) `getButton()` method (this is why the variable has to be `final`). If I didn't do it that way I got compilation errors, because those methods belong to the `AlertDialog`class, not to the `AlertDialog.Builder` class.

Answer (score 1):

if you want dismiss dialog whenever you want then you must need to use Custom Dialog instead of Alert Dialog.

AlertDialog always dismiss when you press Negative or Positive button of AlertDialog.

For more information about custom dialog then [Click here Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

Comment: is thre any way that i will disable the Positive Button and when data is verified it will enable it?????

Comment: in alertDialog no.. bt everything is possible in custom dialog