# How to call same alert Dialog again and again?

Tags: android, alert, android-alertdialog

I have create one `Alert Dialog` which have two `EditText` and two `Button` and I fetch the value of the `EditText` and if value matches then I am doing some operation otherwise I want to call same `AlertDialog` again.But if value differs then I am not able to call the same alert dialog.I don't know where i am doing wrong...

My Code goes like this ::

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private Button btn_click;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_click=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_click);
    btn_click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            showDialog(0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{
    switch (id) 
    {
    case 0:
        // This example shows how to add a custom layout to an AlertDialog
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder login = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        try
        {

            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.login_dialog, null);

            final EditText username_alert = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            final EditText password_alert = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.password);

            login.setTitle("Login").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setView(textEntryView)

            .setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                {
                    /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    String uname_alert=username_alert.getText().toString();
                    String pass_alert=password_alert.getText().toString();

                    if(uname_alert.equals("aaaa") && pass_alert.equals("aaaa"))
                    {
                        //do Something........
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        showDialog(0);
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                {
                    /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return login.create();
    }
    return null;
}
  }
```

Hope my question is clear.......
Please help me ..
Thanks in Advance ..... :)

Comment: you probably need to dismiss you dialog in the onclick ?

Comment: You can call the function that create and show your AlertDialog when you dismiss your dialog like this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42132765/5381331

Answer (score 0):

Befor calling showDialog from dialog you should dismiss the existing dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are creating new dialog every time.

try to keep the dialog you created once to a class level variable and reuse it. Like :

First time
    dialog=login.create();
    return dialog;
Next time onwards
    return dialog only

Comment: This actually isn't true.  The Activity manages calls to `showDialog()` so this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create `AlertDialog` inside `AlertDialog` which is not possible.Instead of that you can use `Toast` to show alert message.

Read this post for custom 
[`AlertDialog`](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application)

Comment: This actually isn't true.  The Activity manages calls to `showDialog()` so this doesn't happen.

Comment: @Devunwired Thanks for the info. Actually I had tried it but not succeeded and I had read somewhere in SO that it is not possible.Is it really possible?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is order of operations.  Your click handler calls `showDialog()` before the dialog is dismissed, so that call does nothing.  Then immediately after the handler method returns, `AlertDialog` calls `dismiss()` on itself (the default behavior) and disappears.

A better implementation of this feature would be to customize `AlertDialog` and intercept the button clicks before the `DialogInterface` handler is called so you can do your validation and not dismiss the dialog at all in that case, rather than trying to make it reappear.  Truth is `AlertDialog` isn't well equipped to handle this case, and the best solution here is to not try to fit the square peg into the round hole and probably just do a custom `Dialog` implementation that does everything you need.

Comment: if you can provide any example,it would be great ... :-)

Comment: This issue has been covered extensively on SO.  Here are just a few solutions others have posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016313/how-to-keep-an-alertdialog-open-after-button-onclick-is-fired or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275677/alert-dialog-in-android-should-not-dismiss

Answer (score 0):

I know this answare is late. But for the future seekers.
I had the same problem and no combination with .hide() .show() and .dismiss() doesn't react. Probably the system need some time and then it is working fine.

```
if (!SDCartConnected())
{
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                showDialog(Const.DIALOG_SDCARD_MISSING);}}, 2000);  
}
```